# How do you track automated data inputs in Google Sheets over time?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that runs a report on data that is automatically updated. What I would like to do is compare the new inputs with the old inputs to determine if the changes were positive or negative. How would you go about automating a sheet to track these changes?

- Changes happen monthly
- there would be a score 1-100; 100 being the best
- would like to store this data over time for a historical view

Any advice would surely be appreciated

The numbers in each criteria change every month producing a score at the end of the table called Current Score

[image]

This score is then pulled into the historical tab as the "Current Score"

What I would like to see happen is that the Current score be saved every month and processed with a percentage change month over month

[image]

So I would need a function that stores a copy of the results before they change, processes a new score, and then calculates the difference between the two. Example here is the Dec score (stored values) compared to the most recent score.

Here is a link to the working example
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ImbRhWqGjvIx2CFRKapZ2wmxC9qpSKxxCbHr5tPOBOs/edit#gid=0

Comment: I would like to help you but I need more information to understand your scenario.

How you sheet looks like? How do you know which inputs you need to compare? The score represent the value of the inputs?

It would be very helpful if you show a breve result of how your sheet looks and how it would look after the automation.

Comment: @fullfine thank you for your reply. I have included more context. Please let me know if you would like more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

You can automate this process by using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script). Open the script editor by clicking on `Tools > Script Editor`. It is based on [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/DEFAULT.asp) and allows you to create, access and modify Google Sheets files with a service called [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet).

In addition, you can use [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to run the script automatically once a month. To set it up, click `Triggers` in the left bar, then `Add Trigger` and select `Time-driven` in `Select event source`. You can now specify the `month timer` and the exact day and hour you want the script to run. However, I recommend that you do some testing before setting up the trigger to check that you get the desired results. You can test the code by clicking `Run` in the `Editor`.

### Explanation of the code

There are three functions in the code. The main function is called `updateScores` and it does what you described in the question. It takes the current score, stores it in a new column and calculates the difference from the last month. Try this function and if you like the result, you can put the trigger in the `main` function. This way, the trigger calls `main` which its only responsibility is to call the other two functions. The first is `updateScores`, which I have already explained, and the second is `clearScores`, which clears all the values of `Reports` so you don't have to do it manually and you can start writing the new values for the new month.

I have added some comments so you can understand what each line does.

```
var lr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('report').getLastRow()

function updateScores() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Historical')
  var currentValues = ss.getRange('B2:B'+lr).getDisplayValues() // get current score
  ss.insertColumnsAfter(2,2) // insert two new columns (current score and percent difference)
  ss.getRange('D2:D'+lr).setValues(currentValues)  // paste stored score
  ss.getRange('C2:C'+lr).setFormula('=if(D2=0,"N/A",B2/D2-1)') // apply formula for last stored scores
  ss.getRange('E2:E'+lr).setFormula('=if(F2=0,"N/A",D2/F2-1)') // correct formula reference
  ss.getRange('E2:E'+lr).copyFormatToRange(ss,3,3,2,lr) // copy format percent
  ss.getRange('F2:F'+lr).copyFormatToRange(ss,4,4,2,lr) // copy format scores

  var month = new Date().toString().split(' ')[1] // get current month
  ss.getRange('D1').setValue(month + ' score') // write current month on last stored scores
  var diff = ss.getRange('E1').getDisplayValue() // get diff symbol
  ss.getRange('C1').setValue(diff) // write diff 

}

function clearScores(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('report')
  ss.getRange('B2:G'+lr).clear()
}

function main(){
  updateScores()
  clearScores()
}
```

Comment: If the range of data changes +/- how could I make this function adapt to less or more rows?

Comment: You can define a global variable that marks the number of elements and substitute it in the code in every place you put `22`. You can specify the number manually or use the `getLastRow()` function.

Comment: I added and called the below variable and replaced 22 but I am still not able to pull the formulas down with the current set up. How should I append the above code you shared to get it to work?
var lr = ss.getLastRow();

Comment: I made my working sheet editable and included your changes here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ImbRhWqGjvIx2CFRKapZ2wmxC9qpSKxxCbHr5tPOBOs/edit#gid=0